# Is it possible to have a maven project with a parent POM *and* modules?

Tags: maven

I currently have a maven project that declares another POM as its parent. Specifically:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

The project has evolved to the point where it should be broken into sub-modules. So, the packaging would be changed to `pom` and a collection of child modules would be added.

Does maven allow this type of arrangement?

Comment: Simple answer yes.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent